# Why isn't nose2 installing nosetests via pip?

Tags: python, nose

I'm trying to setup nose as my testrunner for GAE.
I created a virtual environment and activated it.

I then attempted to use pip to install nose.
It looks like the install was successful, but for some reason the nosetests binary is not installed.

(env) bryanwheelock@Bryans-MacBook Tue Jan 31 09:46:10 ~/work/flask_TDD
$ pip -v install nose2

```
Collecting nose2   
  1 location(s) to search for versions of nose2:  
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/     
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/     
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/" in the cache     
  No cache entry available  
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/nose2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1339  
  Updating cache with response from "https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/"  
  Caching b/c date exists and max-age > 0  
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/  
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cc/12/2f5257e2aaaf8fbf752a2da34faed4dcc49784581daf47a7045d07a6cf10/nose2-0.6.4.tar.gz#md5=4a50ad87d0713a193532cb4c4dde07b1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/), version: 0.6.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/d5/63/806d5f07ea3fc1f8c4df739cf110d87412850ada0d52d905f1bb9c610793/nose2-0.6.0.tar.gz#md5=7d7bbc18a056ed58da28350b7a1880d3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/), version: 0.6.0  
  Using version 0.6.5 (newest of versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5)  
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/6a/8f203ea5d82590b9e70577be37f6482b791410f6d700a6a14c5299b6ed7d/nose2-0.6.5.tar.gz" in the cache  
  No cache entry available    
  "GET /packages/49/6a/8f203ea5d82590b9e70577be37f6482b791410f6d700a6a14c5299b6ed7d/nose2-0.6.5.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 131682    
  Downloading nose2-0.6.5.tar.gz (131kB)    
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/6a/8f203ea5d82590b9e70577be37f6482b791410f6d700a6a14c5299b6ed7d/nose2-0.6.5.tar.gz#md5=a54888fe41885cbdc168e394dcc38712 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose2/)  
    93% |█████████████████████████████▉  | 122kB 3.0MB/s eta 0:00:01  Updating cache with response from "https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/6a/8f203ea5d82590b9e70577be37f6482b791410f6d700a6a14c5299b6ed7d/nose2-0.6.5.tar.gz"  
  Caching due to etag  
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 2.1MB/s   
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/lb/h33h9bt13kxct_5s7vwq2k2h0000gn/T/pip-build-peH2_I/nose2/setup.py) egg_info for package nose2  
    Running command python setup.py egg_info  
    running egg_info  
    creating pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info  
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/requires.txt  
    writing pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/PKG-INFO  
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/top_level.txt  
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt  
    writing entry points to pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/entry_points.txt  
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'  
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'  
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'  
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution  
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution  
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution  
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/nose2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'  
  Source in /private/var/folders/lb/h33h9bt13kxct_5s7vwq2k2h0000gn/T/pip-build-peH2_I/nose2 has version 0.6.5, which satisfies requirement nose2 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/6a/8f203ea5d82590b9e70577be37f6482b791410f6d700a6a14c5299b6ed7d/nose2-0.6.5.tar.gz#md5=a54888fe41885cbdc168e394dcc38712  
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.1 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from nose2)  
Building wheels for collected packages: nose2  
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for nose2 ...   Destination directory: /var/folders/lb/h33h9bt13kxct_5s7vwq2k2h0000gn/T/tmpvhAiQdpip-wheel-  
  Running command /Users/bryanwheelock/work/flask_TDD/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lb/h33h9bt13kxct_5s7vwq2k2h0000gn/T/pip-build-peH2_I/nose2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/lb/h33h9bt13kxct_5s7vwq2k2h0000gn/T/tmpvhAiQdpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27  
  running bdist_wheel  
  running build  
  running build_py  
  creating build  
  creating build/lib  
  creating build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/__main__.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/_version.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/collector.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/compat.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/config.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/events.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/exceptions.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/loader.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/main.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/result.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/runner.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/session.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/sphinxext.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/suite.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  copying nose2/util.py -> build/lib/nose2  
  creating build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/attrib.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/buffer.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/collect.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/coverage.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/debugger.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/doctests.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/dundertest.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/failfast.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/junitxml.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/layers.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/logcapture.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/mp.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/outcomes.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/printhooks.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/prof.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/result.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  copying nose2/plugins/testid.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins  
  creating build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/eggdiscovery.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/functions.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/generators.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/loadtests.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/parameters.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/testcases.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying nose2/plugins/loader/testclasses.py -> build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader  
  creating build/lib/nose2/tests  
  copying nose2/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests  
  copying nose2/tests/_common.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests  
  creating build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_attrib_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_collect_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_coverage.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_decorators.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_discovery_loader.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_doctests_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_dundertest_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_eggdiscovery_loader.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_junitxml_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_layers_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_loading.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_loadtests_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_logcapture_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_main.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_mp_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_printhooks_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_session.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_such_dsl.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying nose2/tests/functional/test_util.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/functional  
  creating build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_attrib_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_buffer_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_collect_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_collector.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_config.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_debugger_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_decorators.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_doctest_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_dundertest_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_failfast.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_functions_loader.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_generators_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_junitxml.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_layers_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_loader.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_logcapture_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_mp_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_outcomes_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_params_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_plugin_api.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_printhooks_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_prof_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_result.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_session.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_testcase_loader.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_testclass_loader.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_testid_plugin.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying nose2/tests/unit/test_util.py -> build/lib/nose2/tests/unit  
  creating build/lib/nose2/tools  
  copying nose2/tools/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2/tools  
  copying nose2/tools/decorators.py -> build/lib/nose2/tools  
  copying nose2/tools/params.py -> build/lib/nose2/tools  
  copying nose2/tools/such.py -> build/lib/nose2/tools  
  creating build/lib/nose2/backports  
  copying nose2/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib/nose2/backports  
  copying nose2/backports/ordereddict.py -> build/lib/nose2/backports  
  running build_scripts  
  creating build/scripts-2.7  
  copying and adjusting bin/nose2 -> build/scripts-2.7  
  changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/nose2 from 644 to 755  
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel  
  running install  
  running install_lib  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/__main__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/_version.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/backports  
  copying build/lib/nose2/backports/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/backports  
  copying build/lib/nose2/backports/ordereddict.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/backports  
  copying build/lib/nose2/collector.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/compat.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/config.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/events.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/loader.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/main.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/attrib.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/buffer.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/collect.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/coverage.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/debugger.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/doctests.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/dundertest.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/failfast.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/junitxml.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/layers.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/eggdiscovery.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/functions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/generators.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/loadtests.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/parameters.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/testcases.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/loader/testclasses.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins/loader  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/logcapture.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/mp.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/outcomes.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/printhooks.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/prof.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/result.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/plugins/testid.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/plugins  
  copying build/lib/nose2/result.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/runner.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/session.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/sphinxext.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  copying build/lib/nose2/suite.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/_common.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_attrib_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_collect_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_coverage.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_decorators.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_discovery_loader.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_doctests_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_dundertest_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_eggdiscovery_loader.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_junitxml_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_layers_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_loading.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_loadtests_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_logcapture_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_main.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_mp_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_printhooks_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_session.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_such_dsl.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/functional/test_util.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/functional  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_attrib_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_buffer_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_collect_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_collector.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_config.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_debugger_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_decorators.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_doctest_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_dundertest_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_failfast.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit    
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_functions_loader.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_generators_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_junitxml.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_layers_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_loader.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_logcapture_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_mp_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_outcomes_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_params_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_plugin_api.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_printhooks_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_prof_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_result.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_session.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_testcase_loader.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_testclass_loader.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_testid_plugin.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tests/unit/test_util.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tests/unit  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tools  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tools/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tools  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tools/decorators.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tools  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tools/params.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tools  
  copying build/lib/nose2/tools/such.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2/tools  
  copying build/lib/nose2/util.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2  
  running install_egg_info  
  running egg_info  
  writing requirements to nose2.egg-info/requires.txt  
  writing nose2.egg-info/PKG-INFO  
  writing top-level names to nose2.egg-info/top_level.txt  
  writing dependency_links to nose2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt  
  writing entry points to nose2.egg-info/entry_points.txt  
  reading manifest file 'nose2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'  
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'  
  warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution  
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution  
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution  
  writing manifest file 'nose2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'  
  Copying nose2.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2-0.6.5-py2.7.egg-info  
  running install_scripts  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2-0.6.5.data  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2-0.6.5.data/scripts  
  copying build/scripts-2.7/nose2 -> build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2-0.6.5.data/scripts  
  changing mode of build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2-0.6.5.data/scripts/nose2 to 755  
  creating build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/wheel/nose2-0.6.5.dist-info/WHEEL  
done  
  Stored in directory: /Users/bryanwheelock/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/24/ee/aa/42b8d1665ee5de70be75f94bc44a712ad69c221b452540e1ea  
  Removing source in /private/var/folders/lb/h33h9bt13kxct_5s7vwq2k2h0000gn/T/pip-build-peH2_I/nose2    
Successfully built nose2  
Installing collected packages: nose2  

  changing mode of /Users/bryanwheelock/work/flask_TDD/env/bin/nose2-2.7 to 755  
  changing mode of /Users/bryanwheelock/work/flask_TDD/env/bin/nose2 to 755  
Successfully installed nose2-0.6.5    
Cleaning up...
```

(env) bryanwheelock@Bryans-MacBook Tue Jan 31 10:22:13 ~/work/flask_TDD
$ nosetests
-bash: nosetests: command not found
(env) bryanwheelock@Bryans-MacBook Tue Jan 31 10:22:19 ~/work/flask_TDD
$ find / -name nosetests 2>/dev/null
(env) bryanwheelock@Bryans-MacBook Tue Jan 31 10:43:24 ~/work/flask_TDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command to run would be `nose2` instead of `nosetests`, isn't it?

As shown in the installation output

```
changing mode of /Users/bryanwheelock/work/flask_TDD/env/bin/nose2-2.7 to 755  
changing mode of /Users/bryanwheelock/work/flask_TDD/env/bin/nose2 to 755
```